# an interesting Galois extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

> Let $x,y$ be variables. Let $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $n=|ad-bc|$.
>   Show that $L=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ is a Galois extension of
>   $K=\mathbb{C}(x^ay^b,x^cy^d)$ of degree $n$. Find $\text{Gal}(L/K)$.

What I need to show here is $|\text{Aut}(L/K)|=[L:K]=n$, i.e. number of automorphisms from $L$ to itself, keeping $K$ as fixed field, equals the extension degree $n$. But $n=|ad-bc|$ and those powers in $x,y$ in the subfield $K$ is confusing me to prove that equality above. Also I'm unable to construct the Galois group of $L$ over $K$. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would look for automorphisms of the form $(x,y)\mapsto(\zeta^rx,\zeta^sy)$
where $\zeta=\exp(2\pi i/n)$. These are always automorphisms of $L=\Bbb C(x,y)$
and fix all the elements of $K$ iff
$$ar+bs\equiv cr+ds\equiv0\pmod n.\tag1$$
I reckon that $(1)$ has $n$ distinct solutions $(r,s)$ modulo $n$, giving
you all the automorphisms you need.

Comment: So we need to construct by Frobenius automorphism and then use Bézout's identity?